# Find most Opportunities by Maximum Number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I just want to ask how to solve this problem, I want to look up data by Serial Number Column to return name Column, but serial number have number in different column?
I just want to look up the serial number by maximum number to show name.

[image]

Comment: If your list is always sorted you could use `XLOOKUP` and search last to first:  `=XLOOKUP(E2,$B$2:$B$9,$C$2:$C$9,,,-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try This

its to return Name by MAX point in column A

```
=INDEX(C2:C9,MATCH(TRUE,(B2:B9=D2),(MAX(A2:A9))))
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Could be reduced to:
`=INDEX($C$2:$C$9,MATCH(1,N($B$2:$B$9=E2),1))` this is provided that the range is sorted.

Comment: This will fail for unsorted data in `repeated serial` column.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FILTER()` function with `MAXIFS()`. Try-

```
=FILTER($C$2:$C$9,($B$2:$B$9=E2)*($A$2:$A$9=MAXIFS($A$2:$A$9,$B$2:$B$9,E2)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If unsorted:

`=@LET(s,SORT($A$2:$C$9,1,-1),FILTER(DROP(s,,2),INDEX(s,,2)=E2))`

This sorts the whole range on the first column, descending.
Then we filter the 3rd column where the 2nd column equals the search string.

If sorted you could use Sunny's solution: `=INDEX($C$2:$C$9,MATCH(1,N($B$2:$B$9=E2),1))`

This finds the row number of the last value in column B that equals the search string and returns the value of column C in that row.